# How to add view count in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a post website and I would like to implement the functionality to add a view count to each post. I think it should be considered with my backend, which is Cloud Firestore.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is it Cloud Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: It is cloud firestore, I am sorry for the lack of detail.

Comment: So to understand better, you want to increment a counter each time a post is viewed, right?

Comment: Exactly, would you be able to figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to increment a counter each time a post is viewed, then you should create a document in which you should add a property of type number like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- data (collection)
        |
        --- counters (document)
              |
              --- $postId: 125
```

The name of the field should be the post ID and the value should be a number. Each time a post is displayed you should simply increment this value. Since you always need to increment the number by one, there is no need to use transactions but an [increment operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).